# Geolocation map, blanc in Ionic2

Tags: ionic-framework, geolocation, ionic2

I want to create an map in my application to show my location with a marker.
I'm using ionic 2 but got blanco page:
http://prntscr.com/dx5czu

This is my code in map.html:

```
<ion-header>

   <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Map</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content>

     <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button (click)="addMarker()"><ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>Add Marker</button>
    </ion-buttons>  

     <div #map id="map"></div>  
</ion-content>
```

And my code in map.ts:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef  } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation } from 'ionic-native';

declare var google;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-map',
  templateUrl: 'map.html'
})

export class Map {


 @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
  map: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap(){

    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

      let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

      let mapOptions = {
        center: latLng,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }

      this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);

    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });

  }

  addMarker(){

  let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: this.map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: this.map.getCenter()
  });

  let content = "<h4>Information!</h4>";          

  this.addInfoWindow(marker, content);

}
addInfoWindow(marker, content){

  let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: content
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
    infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
  });

}

}
```

There are no errors given.

Comment: are you running in some device? plugins dont work on browser with serve

Comment: ow no, did it in firefox, will try on my android device

Comment: cordova plugins only work in emulator/device or alternatively you can add browser as a platform(not sure if all plugins will work in this case)

Comment: Added android, now fixing some problems with JDK

Comment: remember to add styling otherwise you will simply see the black page

Answer (score 0):

This plugin just wordk in device mobile

Answer (score 0):

The thing is your code is perfect except the following lines

> ionViewDidLoad(){
>       this.loadMap();   }

ionViewDidLoad is in the old version of ionic. To make it working you can push this.loadMap(); in the constructor. So the new code will look like

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.loadMap();
}
```

For more information, you can visit my github repository https://github.com/darpanpathak/LocationTrackerApp